# Mockito: Calling overloaded version of method

Tags: mockito

I am new to Mockito and trying to handle a scenario.

I have a class that i am spying on;

```
//Production Code Starts

class LoginRequest {
    final Callable<String> buildRequest() {
        callABC();
        callXYZ();
        Callable<String> callableObject = createCallable();
        return  callableObject;
    }
    final Callable<String> buildRequest(CallBack callBackObject) {
        callABC();
        callXYZ();
        Callable<String> callableObject = createCallable(callBackObject);
        return  callableObject;
    }
}

LoginRequest createLoginRequest() {
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    return loginRequest; 
}

Callable<String> callable = loginRequest.buildRequest();
Netowrk.submit(callable);

//Production Code ends
```

Now, What I want is, that when call to

```
loginRequest.buildRequest()
```

is made it should instead be propagated to the parameter version of the method;
so instead of calling

```
buildRequest()
```

it should call

```
buildRequest(callBackObject);
```

So I have tried the following;

```
//Test Code Starts
LoginRequest createLoginRequest() {
    final LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();

    final LoginRequest spy = Mockito.spy(loginRequest);

    final CallBack callBackObject = new CallBack()//my CallBack object

    Mockito.when(spy.buildRequest()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Callable<?>>() {

        @Override
        public Callable<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                throws Throwable {

                Callable<String> callable = spy.buildRequest(callBackObject);
            return callable;
        }
    });
    return spy;
}
```

I was expecting that when

```
loginReuest.buildRequest()
```

be called from production code it would propagated to 
    Answer.answer() {}
and then to

```
buildRequest(callBackObject);
```

from there.

However what is happening is, that when call to original

```
loginReuest.buildRequest()
```

method from the production code is made, it actually calls the original

```
buildRequst()
```

and from there call to

```
callABC()
```

is made, which in turn calls my anonymous

```
Answer.answer();
```

and end up calling

```
callable = spy.buildRequest(callBackObject);
```

and enters in recursive calls and then stack overflow.

Is there a better way better to do this kind of thing.

I appreciate your help

Thanks
Big O

Comment: Mockito can't mock final methods.

Comment: @JBNizet  is there any other alternative that you know?

Comment: AFAIK, Powermock can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerMock to test final methods:

- Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassWithFinal.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use PowerMock.createMock(ClassWithFinal.class) to create a mock object for all methods of this class (let's call it mockObject).
- Use PowerMock.replay(mockObject) to change the mock object to replay mode.
- Use PowerMock.verify(mockObject) to change the mock object to verify mode.

You have some examples in this page:

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal

You can also use mockito with powermock:

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13